# External Annotations for ReSharper

Tags: annotations, resharper

I'm trying to create [external annotations](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Code_Analysis__External_Annotations.html) for `System.IO.StreamReader.ReadToEndAsync`. I've been looking at other questions on the topic, and tried to decipher what to do from those, and from how already existing external annotations look.

Right now I have:

- A file named `4.0.0.0.Annotations.xml`, located in;
- [user]\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Installations\ReSharperPlatformVs14\ExternalAnnotations\mscorlib

The contents of the annotation file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<assembly name="mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0">
  <member name="M:System.IO.StreamReader.ReadToEndAsync()">
    <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.NotNullAttribute.#ctor" />
  </member>
</assembly>
```

I want to convince the code inspection that `ReadToEndAsync` will not return `null`, but it doesn't seem to be working (still getting warnings). Tried different naming, restarted Visual Studio and stuff, but to no avail.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't realize that there may be several *ExternalAnnotations* folders with the ReSharper installation. In my case, the solution was to move the `mscorlib` folder I created for the `4.0.0.0.Annotations.xml` file to:

> [user]\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Installations\
>   **ReSharperPlatformVs14_000** \ExternalAnnotations

Also, the syntax for annotating a method without parameters does not seem to include parentheses, so I also removed those, changing `name="M:System.IO.StreamReader.ReadToEndAsync()"` to `name="M:System.IO.StreamReader.ReadToEndAsync"`.